# Let $ \mathbb{R}[x] $ be the polynomial ring over the field $ \mathbb{R} $

Tags: ring-theory

Let $ \mathbb{R}[x] $ be the polynomial ring over the field  $ \mathbb{R} $ in one variable.  Let  $ I \subseteq \mathbb{R}[x] $  is an ideal. Then

$(a) $ $ I $ is maximal ideal if and only if the quotient ring $ \mathbb{R}[x] / I $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{R} $.

$$ $$ I know that if $ M /I $ is a field then $ I $ is the maximal ideal. Here $ \mathbb{R}[x] /I $ is a field (isomorphic to the field $ \mathbb{R} $ ) , so $ I $ should be maximal ideal . But the answer says  $ No $. **Can I get some help ?**

Comment: How about the maximal ideal $I=\langle x^2+1\rangle$. The ring ${\mathbb R}[x]/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 4):

The assertion is false.

Since $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, its maximal ideals are those generated by an irreducible (monic) polynomial. There are two kinds of irreducible monic polynomials:

1. $x-a$, for $a\in \mathbb{R}$; the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x-a)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$
2. $x^2+bx+c$, with $b^2-4c<0$; the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+bx+c)$ (with $b^2-4c<0$) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

The counterexample with $x^2+1$ is sufficient to disprove the statement.